# Nesting SetOnClickListener

Tags: android

Can you nest an OnClickListener i.e.

```
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 add = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bAdd);
 add.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                 // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                          setContentView(R.layout.secondary);
                          sub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bSub);   

            }
```

Is it Valid ? Assuming that there is a Button called Sub in activity_main.xml when clicked should go to another view ?

Comment: You can assume. But, this is not a proper way. Just create a new activity, and, put your `secondary` xml part and `sub` buttons in that activity's `oncreate()`

Comment: Create a new activity like another class or oncreate() in the same class?This might seem silly but I am very new to Android

Comment: What's your requirement?

Comment: Make a application to save contacts.
1. First View is the Contacts List View with an Add COntact Button at the end.

2.When One of the contact is clicked,a new view opens up with a picture, name and 3 phone numbers and an Edit Button.

3.when Edit is pressed , one more view opens up with options to edit Name, numbers etc. and an Update button.

4.The New contact view is similar to the Edit view with a save Button

Comment: Make two activity. One is for Listing the contacts and another one is for add/edit contact. Simply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes You can,but which is not good practice...
Why cant You use Two `Activities` and Use `Intents` to switch them..:)

Sample code..

`public class MainActivity extends Activity {`

```
Button buttonone;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    buttonone = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonone);
    buttonone.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,
                    SecondaryActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

`}`

`public class SecondaryActivity extends Activity {`

```
Button buttontwo;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.secondary);
    buttontwo = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttontwo);
    buttontwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
```

//              Do Whatever...
            `}
        });`

```
}
```

`}`